# How to set prefect_count parameter to rabbitMQ from WSO2?

Tags: rabbitmq, wso2

I am making a consumer of rabbitMQ on WSO2 I need to send the message to one service one at the time I know that rabbitMQ has a setting call `prefetch` for that but I di not see the parameter on the wso2 [documentation](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/inbound-endpoints/event-based-inbound-endpoints/rabbitmq-inbound-endpoint-properties/), any one knows other way to do this? Thanks in advance

My inbound endpoint looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<inboundEndpoint name="RabbitMQConsumerTesting" onError="SalesOrderQueueErrorSeq" protocol="rabbitmq" sequence="HandlerRabbitMessage" suspend="false" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <parameters>
        <parameter name="sequential">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="coordination">true</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.connection.factory">AMQPConnectionFactory</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.host.name">my_host</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.port">5672</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.user.name">my_user</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.password">my_password</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.queue.name">my_queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.exchange.name">my_queue</parameter>
        <parameter name="rabbitmq.server.virtual.host">my_vhost</parameter>
    </parameters>
</inboundEndpoint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the **prefetch** value is used to specify how many messages are being sent at the same time in RabbitMQ. You can set the prefetch message count by using the below property in the latest WSO2MI-7.1.0 server[[1](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/synapse-properties/inbound-endpoints/event-based-inbound-endpoints/rabbitmq-inbound-endpoint-properties/#!)].

```
rabbitmq.channel.consumer.qos
```

Please note that if a value is not set, 0 will be used as the default value.